# How to speed up insert in cloudsql

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I can not change this global parameter in google cloud.
set global innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0

How to speed up insert in cloudSQL?

I have tried use bulk insert and any other flags. But it dos not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change every parameter you want for Cloud SQL since it is a Google managed service. Anyway, the innodb_flsuh_log_at_trx_commit parameter should be kept to the value 1, in general, because it helps InnoDB for being [ACID compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID). If you ever try to modify this parameter you risk loosing some data in your transactions.

Going back to your issue, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/how-tos/performance) you can find a set of tips for improving performance of your Cloud SQL instance.

If you really want to have full control over your databases, you can always opt for [setting your databases on a Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-mysql).